# Java Large Number Operations Shortest Path to One

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, recursion, logic

A week ago I was given a challenge from my professor to make a program that has three operations for large numbers, given as as strings. I could only pass five of the ten test cases and got an A anyway, but I still want to know what you guys would do for this problem, as far as programming techniques or an approach I didn't think of..

You are given a String representation of a number that is up to 309 digits long. You can preform three operations:
1) Add 1 to the number
2) Subtract 1
3) Divide by 2

the purpose of the program is to find the shortest path, or smallest amount of operations that can be performed on this number so that the result is 1.
ex: given "11"
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 12 -> 11
result: 5 steps
I had two approaches that didn't work 100%:
1: start from one or the number itself and recursively step through each possible answer until number is reached within a maximum number of steps (eg. 11, 20).
2: define all possible answers with the help of a 2-d boolean array with all possible permutaions, then step through the possible movesets one by one. this array works as a map conceptually.

Both of these approaches had limited success, wether i encountered a stackoverflow error or just ran out of memory with my large arrays. This forced me to limit the number of steps so the code could function somewhat successfully. What would be your approach?

**EDIT** 1:30pm
attempt 1(sorry, it has been edited severely, hence why it wasn't shown earlier...):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Answer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(answer(str));
    }
    // System.out.println(answer("15"));
}

private static BigInteger minNumOfJumps;
private static BigInteger big2 = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
/** smallest Number of jumps reached so far */
private static BigInteger smallestAmountOfJumps;

public static int answer(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BigInteger src = new BigInteger(string);
    // BigInteger currentJump = BigInteger.ZERO; //used to initialize the
    // nodes
    // minNumOfJumps = src.divide(big2).add(BigInteger.ONE); //this must
    // execute...
    minNumOfJumps = new BigInteger("14"); // this must execute...
    smallestAmountOfJumps = new BigInteger(minNumOfJumps.toString());
    // System.out.println(minNumOfJumps);
    Node n = new Node(src); // ...before this

    return Integer.parseInt(getSmallestAmountOfJumps().toString());
    // System.out.println(n.getSmallestAmountOfJumps().toString());
}

public static BigInteger getBig2() {
    return big2;
}

public static void setBig2(BigInteger big2) {
    Answer.big2 = big2;
}

public static BigInteger getMinNumOfJumps() {
    return minNumOfJumps;
}

public static BigInteger getSmallestAmountOfJumps() {
    return smallestAmountOfJumps;
}

public static void setSmallestAmountOfJumps(String smallestAmountOfJumps) {
    Answer.smallestAmountOfJumps = new BigInteger(smallestAmountOfJumps);
}
}

/*
* I have never made a shortest path algorithm before, so i hope this is toyour
* satisfaction
*/
class Node {

/** number of nodes per creation */
private static final int NUMBER_OF_NODES_PER_NODE = 3;
/** if this number is exceeded, no more jumps are necessary. */ // SAVE THAT
                                                                // THINKING
                                                                // JUICE!
// private static BigInteger POSSIBLE_MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_JUMPS;

private static boolean lastTransformWasRemoveOne;
private static boolean lastTransformWasAddOne;

// if one is the given value(src)
// private boolean isOneReached;
/** if the current path isn't valid */
// private boolean threadIsBroken;
// value passed during creation
private BigInteger src;
// current jump
private BigInteger currentJump;

// all possible transformations during next jump
// private Node[] path;

private Node(BigInteger src, BigInteger jump) {
    currentJump = jump;
    this.src = src;
    // POSSIBLE_MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_JUMPS = Answer.getMinNumOfJumps();
    // this.path = new Node[NUMBER_OF_NODES_PER_NODE];

    // 0 = remove | 1 = add | 2 = divide
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_NODES_PER_NODE; i++) {
        // System.out.println("i: " + i);
        // System.out.println("src: " + src);
        // System.out.println("compare: " +
        // currentJump.compareTo(smallestAmountOfJumps));
        // System.out.println("currentJump: " + currentJump);
        // System.out.println("smallestAmountOfJumps: " +
        // smallestAmountOfJumps);
        if (src.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0) {
            if (currentJump.subtract(Answer.getSmallestAmountOfJumps()).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == -1) {
                Answer.setSmallestAmountOfJumps(currentJump.toString());
                // this below may break the code, but i think it fits with
                // the logic
                break;
            }
        } else if (i == 0) { // remove 1
            // System.out.println(lastTransformWasAddOne);
            // System.out.println("compare: " +
            // currentJump.compareTo(smallestAmountOfJumps));
            // System.out.println("currentJump: " + currentJump);
            // System.out.println("smallestAmountOfJumps: " +
            // smallestAmountOfJumps);
            if (!lastTransformWasAddOne && currentJump.compareTo(Answer.getSmallestAmountOfJumps()) < 0) {
                lastTransformWasRemoveOne = true;
                Node n = new Node(transform(i), currentJump.add(BigInteger.ONE));
            }
        } else if (i == 1 && !lastTransformWasRemoveOne
                && currentJump.compareTo(Answer.getSmallestAmountOfJumps()) < 0) { // add
                                                                                    // 1
            lastTransformWasAddOne = true;
            Node n = new Node(transform(i), currentJump.add(BigInteger.ONE));
        } else if (src.mod(Answer.getBig2()) == BigInteger.ZERO
                && currentJump.compareTo(Answer.getSmallestAmountOfJumps()) < 0) { // divide
                                                                                    // by
                                                                                    // 2
            lastTransformWasRemoveOne = false;
            lastTransformWasAddOne = false;
            Node n = new Node(transform(i), currentJump.add(BigInteger.ONE));
        } else if (currentJump.compareTo(Answer.getSmallestAmountOfJumps()) == 0)
            break;
    }
}

private BigInteger transform(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (i == 0) ? src.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
            : (i == 1) ? src.add(BigInteger.ONE) : (i == 2) ? src.divide(Answer.getBig2()) : BigInteger.ZERO;
}

/**
 * To be called once and only once.
 */
public Node(BigInteger src) {
    this(src, BigInteger.ZERO);
}
```

}`

and this is another attempt:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class AnswerLessProficient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            str = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(answer(str));
        }
        // System.out.println(answer("15"));
    }

    private static boolean notFirstCall;
    private static boolean pathIsSet;
    private static boolean[][] boolArray;
    private static final String ZERO = "0";
    private static final BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.ONE.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    private static int maximumSteps;
    private static int maximumPermutations;
    private static ArrayList<byte[]> listOfPaths;
    private static Set<byte[]> setOfPaths;
    // private static final int maximumPermutations = halfMaximumPermutations *
    // 2;
    // private static byte[][] path;
    private static BigInteger src;
    private static int steps;
    private static BigInteger tempSrc;
    private static byte[] tempPath;
    // private static boolean followThePathsWithAlternateRoutesWasCalledOnce;

    public static int answer(String s) {
        // listOfPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        src = new BigInteger(s);
        tempSrc = new BigInteger(s);
        maximumSteps = 9;
        steps = maximumSteps;
        maximumPermutations = (int) Math.pow(2, maximumSteps);
        if (!notFirstCall) {
            tempPath = new byte[maximumSteps];
            setOfPaths = new HashSet<>();
            int mercyVar = (int) Math.pow(2, maximumSteps);
            // path = new byte[maximumPermutations][maximumSteps];
            // boolArray = new boolean[maximumPermutations][maximumSteps];
            for (int i = 0; i < mercyVar; i++) {
                listOfPaths = new ArrayList<>();
                String bin = (Integer.toBinaryString(i));
                while (bin.length() < maximumSteps)
                    bin = (ZERO + bin);
                char[] chars = bin.toString().toCharArray();
                byte[] tempPath = new byte[maximumSteps];
                for (int j = 0; j < maximumSteps; j++) {
                    // if (!pathIsSet)
                    // path[j] = -1;
                    if (chars[j] == '0') {
                        tempPath[j] = 2;
                        // path[i][j] = 2;
                        // boolArray[i][j] = true;
                    } else {
                        tempPath[j] = -1;
                        // path[i][j] = -1;
                    }
                }
                 //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempPath));
                listOfPaths.add(tempPath);
                setOfPaths.add(tempPath);
                findAltRoute(listOfPaths.size() - 1, maximumSteps - 1);
            }
            /*
             * for (int i = mercyVar, j = 0; i < maximumPermutations; i++, j++)
             * { for (int k = 0; k < maximumSteps; k++) { if (path[j][k] == -1)
             * { path[i][k] = 1; } else { path[i][k] = 2; } } }
             */

            // for (byte[] bs : setOfPaths) {
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bs));
            // }
            /*
             * for (int i = maximumSteps - 1, k = 0; i >= 0 &&
             * tempSrc.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0; i--, k++) { if
             * (tempSrc.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0) if (k < steps) { steps =
             * k; maximumSteps = steps; System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bs));
             * break; } else break; if (bs[i] == 2 && tempSrc.mod(TWO) !=
             * BigInteger.ZERO) break; tempSrc = transform(tempSrc, bs[i]); }
             * tempSrc = src.add(BigInteger.ZERO);
             */
            // }

            // System.out.println(bin);
            /*
             * for (int j = 0; j < maximumSteps && i >= halfMaximumPermutations;
             * j++) { // if (!pathIsSet) // path[j] = -1; if (chars[j + 1] ==
             * '0') { path[i][j] = 2; // boolArray[i][j] = true; } else {
             * path[i][j] = 1; } }
             */
            // System.out.println(bin);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(path[i]));
            // pathIsSet = true;
            notFirstCall = true;
        }
        justFollowThePath();
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(path[0]));
        // System.out.println
        // (Arrays.toString(path[(int) (maximumPermutations/2)-1]));
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(path[maximumPermutations-1]));

        /**
         * 561-508-2204 george rubio debt forgiveness; 305-709-8255
         */
        // for (int i = 0; i < maximumPermutations; i++) {
        // followThePathsWithAlternateRoutes(path[i], maximumSteps - 1);
        // }

        // followThePathsWithAlternateRoutesWasCalledOnce = false;

        /*
         * for (int i = 0; i < maximumPermutations; i++) { for (int k = 0; k <
         * maximumSteps; k++) {
         * 
         * }
         * 
         * for (int k = maximumSteps - 1; k > 0; k--) {
         * 
         * } }
         */

        // for (boolean[] bs : boolArray) {
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bs));
        // }

        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boolArray[maximumPermutations -
        // 1]));
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(path));

        return steps;
    }

    private static void findAltRoute(int listIndex, int startingSearchIndex) {
        if (listOfPaths.get(listIndex)[startingSearchIndex] == -1) {
            // followThePathsWithAlternateRoutesWasCalledOnce = true;
            // recurAlt(tempPath, maximumSteps - 1, maximumSteps - 1, (byte) 1,
            // maximumSteps - 1);
            for (int i = startingSearchIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (listOfPaths.get(listIndex)[i] == 2) {
                    returnAltRoute(listIndex, i + 1, startingSearchIndex, (byte) 1, i);
                    findAltRoute(listIndex + 1, i);
                    return;
                }

                else if (i == 0) {
                    returnAltRoute(listIndex, i, startingSearchIndex, (byte) 1);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = startingSearchIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (listOfPaths.get(listIndex)[i] == -1 && listOfPaths.get(listIndex)[i + 1] == 2) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    for (int k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                        if (listOfPaths.get(listIndex)[k] == 2 && listOfPaths.get(listIndex)[k + 1] == -1) {
                            // recurAlt(tempPath, i, k + 1, (byte) 1, k);
                            returnAltRoute(listIndex, k + 1, i, (byte) 1, k);
                            findAltRoute(listIndex, i);
                        }
                        // returnAltRoute(listIndex, 0, i, (byte)1);
                        // return;
                    }
                } else {
                    returnAltRoute(listIndex, 0, i, (byte) 1);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void returnAltRoute(int listIndex, int tempStart, int tempEnd, byte adjust, int returnSearchInt) {
        byte[] tempPath = new byte[listOfPaths.get(listIndex).length];
        for (int i = maximumSteps - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i >= tempStart && i <= tempEnd) {
                tempPath[i] = adjust;
            } else {
                tempPath[i] = listOfPaths.get(listIndex)[i];
            }
        }
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempPath));
        setOfPaths.add(tempPath);
        listOfPaths.add(tempPath);
        maximumPermutations = setOfPaths.size();
        findAltRoute(listIndex, returnSearchInt);
    }

    private static void returnAltRoute(int listIndex, int tempStart, int tempEnd, byte adjust) {
        byte[] tempPath = new byte[listOfPaths.get(listIndex).length];
        for (int i = maximumSteps - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i >= tempStart && i <= tempEnd) {
                tempPath[i] = adjust;
            } else {
                tempPath[i] = listOfPaths.get(listIndex)[i];
            }
        }
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempPath));
        setOfPaths.add(tempPath);
        listOfPaths.add(tempPath);
        maximumPermutations = setOfPaths.size();
    }

    private static void justFollowThePath() {
        for (byte[] bs : setOfPaths) {
            //System.out.println(tempSrc.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < maximumSteps && tempSrc.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0; i++) {
                if (tempSrc.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0)
                    if (i < steps) {
                        steps = i;
                        maximumSteps = steps;
                        //System.out.println(i);
                        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempPath));
                        break;
                    } else
                        break;
                if (bs[i] == 2 && tempSrc.mod(TWO) != BigInteger.ZERO)
                    break;
                tempSrc = transform(tempSrc, bs[i]);
            }
            tempSrc = src.add(BigInteger.ZERO);

        }
    }

    private static void followThePathsWithAlternateRoutes(byte[] tempPath, int startingSearchIndex) {
        if (tempPath[maximumSteps - 1] == -1) {
            // followThePathsWithAlternateRoutesWasCalledOnce = true;
            recurAlt(tempPath, maximumSteps - 1, maximumSteps - 1, (byte) 1, maximumSteps - 1);
        }
        for (int i = startingSearchIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (tempPath[i] == -1 && tempPath[i + 1] == 2) {
                for (int k = i - 1; k > 0; k--) {
                    if (tempPath[k] == 2) {
                        recurAlt(tempPath, i, k + 1, (byte) 1, k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        for (int i = maximumSteps - 1, k = 0; i >= 0 && tempSrc.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0; i--, k++) {
            if (tempSrc.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0)
                if (k < steps) {
                    steps = k;
                    maximumSteps = steps;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempPath));
                    break;
                } else
                    break;
            if (tempPath[i] == 2 && tempSrc.mod(TWO) != BigInteger.ZERO)
                break;
            tempSrc = transform(tempSrc, tempPath[i]);
        }
        tempSrc = src.add(BigInteger.ZERO);
    }

    private static BigInteger transform(BigInteger temp, byte i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (i == -1) ? tempSrc.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
                : (i == 1) ? tempSrc.add(BigInteger.ONE) : (i == 2) ? tempSrc.divide(TWO) : null;
    }

    private static void recurAlt(byte[] tempPath, int tempStart, int tempEnd, byte adjust, int returnSearchInt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] temp = new byte[tempPath.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (i >= tempStart && i <= tempEnd)
                temp[i] = adjust;
            else
                temp[i] = tempPath[i];
        }
        followThePathsWithAlternateRoutes(temp, returnSearchInt);
    }

}
```

there are other things i've tried, but you can see where i'm going. Any pointers?

---

Comment: show what you have up to now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number is even, divide by 2. If the number is 3 mod 4, add one unless the number is actually 3. Otherwise, subtract one. Repeat until you get to 1.

Here's a proof.

First note that if the number is even, it only makes sense to divide by 2. Because if you perform some number (say 2k) of +1 or -1, then divide by 2 that's the same as dividing by two and then adding or subtracting k 1's. So by dividing by two first, you save operations.

So the only question is whether to add or subtract 1 when the number is odd. You can prove by induction that the given strategy is correct.

An odd number n is either 4x+1 or 4x+3. Note that any sequence of operations (when we're dividing by 2 whenever possible) will at some point reach either x or x+1.

We'll consider each of these in turn, and count shortest paths to x and x+1. (Checking that I've correctly identified shortest paths is omitted).

In the first case (4x+1), by subtracting one first we can get to x in 3 steps (4x+1->4x->2x->x) and x+1 in 4 steps (4x+1->4x->2x->x->x+1). By adding one first, we can get to x in 4 steps (4x+1->4x+2->2x+1->2x->x) and x+1 in 4 steps (4x+1->4x+2->2x+1->2x+2->x+1). So we might as well always subtract 1 first.

In the second case (4x+3), by subtracting one first we can get to x in 4 steps (4x+3->4x+2->2x+1->2x->x), and x+1 in 4 steps (4x+3->4x+2->2x+1->2x+2->x+1). By adding one first, we can get to x+1 in 3 steps (4x+3->4x+4->2x+2->x+1), and x in 4 steps (4x+3->4x+4->2x+2->x+1->x). So we might as well always add 1 first in this case.

In the second case, if x=0 (that is n=4*0+3=3), then our reasoning doesn't quite work, since we won't, in fact, reach x. In this case we should subtract one and divide by 2 to reach 1.

The question is labelled java, but here's some pseudocode (actually Python) to produce optimal chains:

```
def chain(n):
    while n:
        print n,
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n //= 2
        elif n % 4 == 3 and n != 3:
            n += 1
        else:
            n -= 1

chain(11)
```

Comment: very interesting... i think that actually would have done it. I'll try implementing it for large numbers and get back to you.

Comment: this is incorrect when you enter 15. the answer is supposed to be 5, this returns 6...

Comment: It outputs 15 16 8 4 2 1. What's shorter?

Comment: that was a given answer... im not sure give me a moment

Answer (score 0):

My first approach will be using [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

There are only 2 or 3 state transition ( I assume we can't divide odd number).
But this approach only fast enough for small number.

The second approach will be using [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) with smallest number as heuristic function. For example when I start with "12", I can go to:
"11", "13", "6". I will choose "6" for the next state because it closer to "1".
However this approach still not fast enough.

My third approach will be generate the answer from "1" to "100" then looking for the pattern / formula.

**Edit: remove wrong formula.**

Comment: i had this approach too, but it doesnt work for the application sadly. there is a much simpler solution above.